# What was the first Lego tie-in film or television production?

Tags: lego-group, marketing

Nowadays, it's pretty common for TV shows and films to be released by film studios in agreement with The LEGO Group and tying in to current LEGO set themes - famous examples include the recent films (The LEGO Movie and The LEGO Movie 2: The Second Part), LEGO Star Wars: The Yoda Chronicles, the Legends of Chima TV series, and Ninjago: Masters of Spinjitsu, all of which were released after 2010.

What is the *earliest* television or film production that was officially tied in with a LEGO set or theme or with LEGO bricks in general? The earliest that I was able to find was [Edward and Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_and_Friends) from 1987 that showcased the Fabuland theme, but LEGO was already decades old by then. Was there anything before that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you already answered your own question: The The earliest Lego television production *is* Edward and Friends from 1987 that showcased the Fabuland theme.

From [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_and_Friends):

> It was Lego's first foray into animation and television in general.